# Cordova 2.2.0.jar doesn't work on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0, cordova-3

I am newbie to `PhoneGap`. I want to develope android app with `PhoneGap`. As a beginner, i referred [this link](http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.in/2012/12/first-phonegap-app-with-android-using.html) to create sample app for practicing. Here i have used `Cordova 2.2.0.jar` for developing application.The problem is that app runs successfully on Android<4.4.2. On android 4.2.2, it keep on showing message of "Connecting to device" as shown in demo. I also downloaded `Cordova 3.3.0` from [this page](http://cordova.apache.org/). According to [PhoneGap guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html#Android%20WebViews) there should be `ant jar` in `Android package's /framework directory` but there is no `ant jar` file in that folder.Therefore i decided to use `Cordova 2.2.0.jar`.  I don't know what is this problem. Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are starting with phonegap, I would suggest you just forget about version 2.2.

The link you provided about phonegap 3 is not for creating a new phonegap app, but to integrate a webwiew using phonegap in an existing larger native android app.

To create a new phonegap app, you should follow [the phonegap CLI guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

Or maybe you could use Netbeans version 7.4 or more which now have a "new cordova application" assistant.

Comment: Ok, i am using `Eclipse standard kepler`. Is it possible to develope PhoneGap app with that?

Comment: Sure. Follow steps in http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface for the project creation and http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide for the integration of android project in eclipse

Comment: Finally i successfully created sampleApp of Android-phoneGap integration.Thank you mate.